# Retornar valor do banco de dados para e-mail

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, email

Olá!

Tenho uma dúvida aqui, estou fazendo uma função que pega os dados do Banco de Dados e envia um email com eles, por exemplo: 'Olá {{Nome}}'. ({{Nome}}) Seria o campo que viria do banco de dados.

Consegui fazer com que pegue o valor do DB mas quando coloco no e-mail, apenas fica como object Promise. Preciso de ajuda em relação a isso.

Estou usando Node.JS e o banco de dados é o PostgreSQL

```
let pool = new Pool (config);
```

async function nomes () {
  let destNome = await pool.query('SELECT destinatario_nome FROM dados')
  console.log(destNome.rows[0].destinatario_nome)
}

async function prevEntrega () {
  let destPrevEntrega = await pool.query('SELECT previsao_entrega FROM dados')
  console.log(destPrevEntrega.rows[10].previsao_entrega)
}

nomes();
prevEntrega();

```
var mailOptions = {
  from: 'eduardo@mail.com',
  to: 'eduardo@teste.com',
  subject: 'Email teste',
  html: 'Olá, seja bem-vindo' + nomes() + ', a previsão de entrega é' + prevEntrega() + '.'
};
```

Comment: Podes colocar também o código que vai usar `mailOptions`?

Comment: var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  service: 'gmail',
  auth: {
    user: 'usuario@gmail.com',
    pass: 'senhadousuario'
  }
});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sua função `nomes` é `async`, ou seja, ela retorna uma [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). Então para utilizá-lo você deve usar o operador `await`:

```
const mailOptions = {
  from: 'eduardo@mail.com',
  to: 'eduardo@teste.com',
  subject: 'Email teste',
  html: '
Olá, seja bem-vindo' + await nomes() + ', a previsão de entrega é' + await prevEntrega() + '.'
};
```

Falta também o `return` nas suas funções:

```
const  pool = new Pool (config);

const nomes = async () => {
  const destNome = await pool.query('SELECT destinatario_nome FROM dados');
  console.log(destNome.rows[0].destinatario_nome);
  return destNome.rows[0].destinatario_nome;
};

const prevEntrega = async () => {
  const destPrevEntrega = await pool.query('SELECT previsao_entrega FROM dados');
  console.log(destPrevEntrega.rows[10].previsao_entrega);
  return destPrevEntrega.rows[10].previsao_entrega;
};
```

Uma sugestão de melhoria em relação à busca dos dados é realizar tudo de uma só vez:

```
const pool = new Pool(config);

const buscar = async () => {
  const { rows: { [0]: { destinatario_nome: destinatario, previsao_entrega: previsao } } } = await pool.query('SELECT destinatario_nome, previsao_entrega FROM dados');

  return {
    destinatario,
    previsao,
  };
}
```

E irá utilizar da seguinte forma:

```
const { destinatario, previsao } = await buscar();

const mailOptions = {
  from: 'eduardo@mail.com',
  to: 'eduardo@teste.com',
  subject: 'Email teste',
  html: `Olá, seja bem-vindo ${^destinatario}, a previsão de entrega é ${previsao} .`
};
```

---

> [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)
>
> `Promise` é um objeto usado para processamento assíncrono. Um `Promise` (de "promessa") representa um valor que pode estar disponível agora, no futuro ou nunca.

---

> [`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await)
>
> O operador `await` é utilizado para esperar por uma `Promise`. Ele pode ser usado apenas dentro de uma função `async`.

Comment: Adicionei seu código para verificar se estava correto e me basear nele, mas quando tento enviar um e-mail, retorna o erro Unexpected Identifier. Ocorreu isso quando coloquei o 'await' antes de nome().

Comment: @EduardoNunes o operador `await` só pode ser usado dentro de uma função `async`. A função na qual você está chamando é `async`?

Comment: Ah entendi, não havia lido o comentário acima que destacava isso... Estava tentando usar ele na mensagem que seria enviada por e-mail.

Comment: Agora retorna o erro de 'Await is only valid in async function', acredito que seja pelo 'await buscar()'.

Comment: @EduardoNunes coloca o arquivo completo aqui https://pastebin.com/ e me manda o link pra eu olhar

Comment: https://pastebin.com/EDyBtELx

Comment: @EduardoNunes tenta assim https://pastebin.com/16STWkwa

Comment: Deu certo! Valeu irmão!

Comment: @EduardoNunes não esqueça de aceitar a resposta para que outras pessoas também possam se beneficiar da mesma